# Spoofing different methods within same form laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

So within a single form I want to be able to change the request type between PATCH and DELETE depending on which button has been selected. Here's my code (simplified for readability):

```
<form id="edit-task-form" method="POST" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
    @csrf

    <div>
        <input type="text" id="modal-task-title" name="task_title" placeholder="Title"/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <textarea name="task_desc" id="modal-task-desc" placeholder="Task description." rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="input flex-center-parent">
        <input type="button" value="Delete" id="delete-task"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" id="save-task"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm thinking I could just change the value onclick() with javascript but wondering if anyone knows a more laravel-like way for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use HTML buttons instead of inputs and set the name attribute of the buttons to `_method` allowing you to have form values assigned to them.

```
<div class="input flex-center-parent">
    <button type="submit" name"_method" value="DELETE" id="delete-task">Delete</button>
    <button type="submit" name"_method" value="PATCH" id="save-task">Save</button>
</div>
```